# Select a particular value from a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My original dataset looks very similar to the sample dataset mentioned below:

| id | name | country | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ron | US | HR |
| 2 | John | US | HR |
| 2 | John | US | IT |
| 2 | John | US | IT |
| 3 | Kelly | US | IT |
| 3 | Kelly | US | IT |
| 4 | Dave | US | Sales |
| 4 | Dave | US | IT |
| 4 | Dave | US | IT |
| 4 | Dave | US | Marketing |
| 5 | Nora | US | IT |

I want to display the names of those employees who have worked only in the IT department. For example, John has worked in both HR and IT, so I would want to exclude his name from my output. What should my approach be in SQL Server?

Based on the above example, my output should look something like the table below:

| id | name | country | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Kelly | US | IT |
| 3 | Kelly | US | IT |
| 5 | Nora | US | IT |

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, one would be to use `not exists`

```
select * 
from t
where department = 'it' 
and not exists (select * from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.department != 'it');
```

Another way would be to use an aggregate window function:

```
select id, name, country, department from (
    select *, 
      Min(department) over(partition by id) mind, 
      Max(department) over(partition by id) maxd
    from t
)t
where mind = maxd and maxd = 'it';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` to group same name and compare each deparment row with `min` and `max` to check if it has only one department as following.

```
select name, min(department) department
from   t
group by name
having min(department) = max(department)
```

And you can filter IT department by adding another condition (`min` is used for department because it is in having statement) as following.

```
select name, min(department) department
from   t
group by name
having min(department) = max(department)
and min(department) = 'IT'
```

And you can get all rows not groupped rows by using it in sub query as following.

```
select *
from   t
where  name in
(
    select name
    from   t
    group by name
    having min(department) = max(department)
    and min(department) = 'IT'
)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=add8a5278770cf889a0e898fce6ad9a7

Comment: This would be fine however the OP's desired results has 3 rows, using group by removes one of the desired rows. Also your *fiddle* appears to be for a different answer.

Comment: @Stu Thank you for your detailed suggestion. I answered with my small phone under my blanket without light in the room, so I did not care much.

Comment: Perhaps concentrate on one task at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name, country, department 
FROM test
WHERE department='IT' AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM test WHERE 
department<>'IT')
ORDER BY id asc;
```

Working as you need, tested in MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for conditional grouping.

```sql
;with cte_EmployeeCounts AS
(
SELECT id, count(*) as Total_Dept, count(case when department = 'IT' THEN 1 END) as Total_IT_Dept
FROM TableName
GROUP BY id
)
SELECT * FROM TableName
where id in  (SELECT id from cte_EmployeeCounts WHERE Total_Dept = Total_IT_Dept)
```